# useHash Angular Tour of heroes Hash-as-a-path

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When I'm adding: useHash: true, my routing works for the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial. For one exception: detail/:id

When I'm on url/#/detail/15, the website goes to detail page of 15. After that I change the url to url/#/detail/16, and nothing happens.

However, when I go back to previous page, and than change the url to 16, it functions like normal.

Did I miss something?

Here's my code from the routing module, no other components have been adjusted.

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { ErrorpageComponent } from './errorpage/errorpage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'index', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
  { path: 'index', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorpageComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]

})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

link to the angular tutorial:
https://angular.io/tutorial